# how could I replace gnuplot output to image (keep it open) output from inside PSQL?

Tags: gnuplot, psql

how could I replace gnuplot output to image (keep it open in its own window)  output from inside PSQL ?

So I would like to output that on graphical graphic to make it more readable by my users,

I mean when they start the script they get a popup Xorg window with the graph until they close themselves that window.

currently, I use this kind of test :

```
francois@zaphod:~/Documents/DEV/sh/pgsqlplot$ cat commands                                                                   
\t                                                                                                                           
\a                                                                                                                           
\f ' '                                                                                                                       
\o | /usr/bin/gnuplot                                                                                                        
select 'set title "My test Graph"; set terminal dumb 128 52; set key off; set ylabel "something"; set xlabel "temp";' || 'plot ''-'' with lines;' ;
select something from temp where date >= '2018-01-01' order by date ;                                                        
\o                                                                                                                           
francois@zaphod:~/Documents/DEV/sh/pgsqlplot$ psql perso < commands
```

So I cat get a terminal pseudo graph  like that :

```
  3000 +-+--------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+-+
       +                      +                       +                      +                       +                      +
       |                                                       *                                                            |
       |                                                       **                                                           |
       |                                                       * *                                                          |
       |                                                       *  *                                                         |
       |                                                       *  *                                                         |
  2500 +-+                                            *       *    *                                                      +-+
```

[...etc...]

I did not find the good help pages neither in gnuplot neither in gluplot documents.
Could you help me to adapt the commands file to use proper options around gnuplot & postgres ?

I tried to use set terminal jpeg large font arial size 2048,768 & \o | /usr/bin/gnuplot --persist but then I get the jpeg binary content on the terminal then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, choose a window terminal. Normally I would expect the default terminal, the terminal which is selected without an explicit `set terminal` command, to be a window terminal. In my case it is the `qt` terminal, but there are other options like `set terminal x11`. You can get a list with the `set terminal` command from within gnuplot. As a first attempt, I would just remove the `set terminal dumb` command.

Second, to keep the window open, I see two possibilities:

1. Adding the `-persist` commandline option when calling gnuplot.

   This closes gnuplot and finishes your script.
2. Using the `pause mouse close` command in the gnuplot script.

   This does not close gnuplot but keeps the possibility to use the mouse and keyboard shortcuts for zooming, adding a grid etc.

Using option 2, we arrive at this script (I have rearranged the lines to avoid scrolling):

```
\t
\a
\f ' ' 
\o | /usr/bin/gnuplot
select 'show terminal';
select 'set title "My test Graph"';
select 'set key off';
select 'set ylabel "something"'; 
select 'set xlabel "temp"'; 
select 'plot ''-'' with lines';
select something from temp where date >= '2018-01-01' order by date ;
select 'e';
select 'pause mouse close';
\o
```

The line `select 'show terminal';` prints `qt` in my case. The line `select 'e';` indicates that 
there is no more data to plot.

With option 1, the line which calls gnuplot would be `\o | /usr/bin/gnuplot -persist`.

---

Just in case you want to switch to a file output, you have to add the name of the output file:

```
select 'set terminal jpeg';
select 'set output "filename.jpg"';
...
select 'plot ...
```

Comment: @francoisP You're welcome. I see that you have tried to switch to jpeg output. If this could be an option, you have to give the output filename, see the update of the answer.